# Python: Multiple Text Files to Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

I'm a little stuck on how exactly to proceed, so a little nudge would be very helpful.

I have ~1800 text files, emails actually, that are in a **repeated format**.

The structure of each file is as follows:

```
From: Person-1 [email@person-1.com]
Sent: Tuesday, April 18, 2017 11:24 AM
To: email@person-2.com
Subject: Important Subject

User, 

Below is your search alert.

Target: text

Attribute: text

Label: abcdef

Time: Apr 18, 2017 11:24 EDT

Full Text: Text of various length exists here. Some files even have links. I'm not sure how I would capture a varied length field.

Recording: abcde & fghijk lmnop
```

That's the gist of it.

I would like to write that into a DF I can store as a CSV.

I would like to end up with maybe something like this?

```
| Target | Attribute |  Label  |  Time  |  Full Text  | Recording | Filename |
|--------|-----------|---------|--------|-------------|-----------|----------|
|    text|       text|   abcdef| (date) |(Full text..)|abcde & f..| 1111.txt |
|   text2|      text2|  abcdef2| (date) |(Full text..)|abcde & f..| 1112.txt |
```

Where the 2nd row is another text file.

I have code to go through all of the text files and print them. Here's that code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

# Take all text files in workingDirectory and put them into a DF.
def convertText(workingDirectory, outputDirectory):
    if workingDirectory == "": workingDirectory = os.getcwd() + "\\" # Returns current working directory, if workingDirectory is empty.
    i = 0
    for txt in os.listdir(workingDirectory): # Iterate through text filess in workingDirectory
        print("Processing File: " + str(txt))
        fileExtension = txt.split(".")[-1]
        if fileExtension == "txt":
            textFilename = workingDirectory + txt # Becomes: \PATH\example.text
            f = open(textFilename,"r")
            data = f.read() # read what is inside
            print data # print to show it is readable

            #RegEx goes here?

            i += 1 # counter
    print("Successfully read " + str(i) + " files.")


def main(argv):
    workingDirectory = "../Documents/folder//" # Put your source directory of text files here
    outputDirectory = "../Documents//" # Where you want your converted files to go.

    convertText(workingDirectory, outputDirectory)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

I guess I would need RegEx, maybe, to parse the files? What would you recommend?

I am not opposed to using R or something else, if it makes more sense.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex should be sufficient for your use case. Using the regex expression [`r"\sTarget:(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/5duzW4/1) you can match everything on the line that matches with `Target:`, then by creating a list of all the fields you wish to match and iterating over them, you build up a dictionary object that stores the values of each field.

Using the [Python CSV library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)  you can create a CSV file and for each `.txt` file in your directory push a row of the matched dictionary fields with `writer.writerow({'Target':'','Attribute':'','Time':'','Filename':'','Label':''})`

**Example:**

```
import os
import sys
import re
import csv 

# Take all text files in workingDirectory and put them into a DF.
def convertText(workingDirectory, outputDirectory):
    with open(outputDirectory+'emails.csv', 'w') as csvfile: # opens the file \PATH\emails.csv
      fields = ['Target','Attribute','Label','Time','Full Text'] # fields you're searching for with regex
      csvfield = ['Target','Attribute','Label','Time','Full Text','Filename'] # You want to include the file name in the csv header but not find it with regex
      writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n', fieldnames=fields)
      writer.writeheader() # writes the csvfields list to the header of the csv

      if workingDirectory == "": workingDirectory = os.getcwd() + "\\" # Returns current working directory, if workingDirectory is empty.
      i = 0
      for txt in os.listdir(workingDirectory): # Iterate through text filess in workingDirectory
          print("Processing File: " + str(txt))
          fileExtension = txt.split(".")[-1]
          if fileExtension == "txt":
              textFilename = workingDirectory + txt # Becomes: \PATH\example.text
              f = open(textFilename,"r")
              data = f.read() # read what is inside

              #print(data) # print to show it is readable
              fieldmatches = {}
              for field in fields:
                regex = "\\s" + field + ":(.*)" # iterates through each of the fields and matches using r"\sTarget:(.*) that selects everything on the line that matches with Target:
                match = re.search(regex, data)
                if match:
                  fieldmatches[field] = match.group(1)
              writer.writerow(fieldmatches) # for each file creates a dict of fields and their values and then adds that row to the csv
              i += 1 # counter
      print("Successfully read " + str(i) + " files.")


def main(argv):
    workingDirectory = "../Documents/folder//" # Put your source directory of text files here
    outputDirectory = "../Documents//" # Where you want your converted files to go.

    convertText(workingDirectory, outputDirectory)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

For processing files this should be fast enough on my machine it took less than a second

```
Successfully read 1866 files.
Time: 0.6991933065852838
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you so much @Alessi 42! This worked like a charm. Now I have just one question. In some instances for the "Full Text" the next few lines are part of the 'Full Text', but for some reason just not included. Is there any way to basically say "All lines before 'Recording' should be part of 'Full Text'"?

Comment: You would include new lines in the dotall selection then set then end terminator to be the next item in the list or miss out the Full text selection and do it after. The regex for this would be `\sFull Text:((.|\n)*?)(Recording:)` see https://regex101.com/r/ODbJrz/3